# Some question to distinguish c++.net cli Managed C++

Tags: visual-c++, command-line-interface

Is C++.Net (not Visual C++), CLI, Managed C++ is the same ? Is they need a framework to run
Managed C++ is CLI or MFC ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed C++ is used to describe the original .NET C++ support in Visual Studio 2002/2003.

C++/CLI is the newer syntax introduced in Visual Studio 2005.

Yes they require the .NET runtime.

MFC is a plain old C++ framework that is neither Managed C++ nor C++/CLI and requires the MFC libraries to be linked but does not require a runtime as such.